# Poner "ñ" en mi App Android hecha en Flutter

Tags: java, flutter

Acabo de entrar a un proyecto con un backend en Java Spring, un Middleware que crea la API tambien en Java, la BD MySQL y la UI en Flutter (no conocia Flutter antes).

Pero en vez de mostrar "Piña" como esta en la BD, muestra esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado usar el dart:convert para importar la lista con UTF 8, pero sigue saliendo el error.

```
import 'dart:convert';

class ProductsProvider {
  Future<List<Product>> loadProducts(
      String urlMiddleware, Client client) async {
    final url = '$urlMiddleware${Constants().getProducts}${client.code}';
    final response = await http.get(url,
        headers: <String, String>{'authorization': Constants().basicAuth});
    print('Url');
    print(url);
    json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
    final List<Product> products = productFromJson(response.body).toList();
    
    return products;
  }
```

Este es el model:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:pil_store/models/EnumValues.dart';

List<Product> productFromJson(String str) => List<Product>.from(json.decode(utf8.decode(str.runes.toList())).map((x) => Product.fromJson(x)));

String productToJson(List<Product> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));
```

No les paso algo similar algun momento? Como lo solucionaron? Gracias cualquier sugerencia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar alguna de estas opciones:

```
responseJson = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));

String stringResponse = Utf8Decoder().convert(resp.body);
Map<String, dynamic> decodedResponse = jsonDecode(stringResponse)
```

Igualmente en tu código, no veo que asignes el `json.decode` a ninguna variable.

Answer (score 0):

En la ventana del navegador del proyecto de android studio podrás encontrar el elemento "build.gradle", haz doble click en él y se te abrirá una ventana con el título "app" y el icono de gradle. Pues bien, en el código debes agregar la siguiente línea:

```
android {
    
    compileOptions.encoding "ISO-8859-1"
```

Comment: Gracias, lo intente pero siguen saliendo esos caracteres raros.